# Remove a custom made drop-down list in the event of click outside

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-events

I made a custom drop-down list. And I want it to function like the select tag in HTML. When I click outside the dropdown list I want it to be removed. But I got problem with it. The code below is working and it is compiled whenever I click on a button that brings forward the drop-down list (`optionContainer`).

```
var optionContainer = document.createElement('div');
optionContainer.className = 'optionContainer';
button.appendChild(optionContainer);

var clickOutsideEvent = function(){
     $(optionContainer).remove();
};
    
$(optionContainer).mouseout(function(){
    $(document).delegate('body','click', clickOutsideEvent);
});
    
$(optionContainer).mouseover(function(){
    $(document).undelegate('body', 'click', clickOutsideEvent);         
});
```

But, I need to add one more line of code to make it complete. The line of code below is added after the last line above unidented.

```
$(document).delegate('body','click', clickOutsideEvent);
```

The weird thing is that this line of code is exactly the same line used on the `mouseout` event. But this line doesn't work.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" - what do you mean? it doesn't add the event handler?

Comment: did you wrap the last line in the $(document).ready call, so it executes when jQuery is loaded?

Comment: @Guss: javascript error. If I for instance add the line after I created the optionContainer, the line below it will not be compiled.

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne: Yes it worked! Maybe you should add the answer

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne: Sorry I was mistaken. I actually triggered the mouseout event during my testing. So the problem remains

Comment: @Guss: I meant after I defined the clickOutsideEvent function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you wrap the last line in the $(document).ready call, so it executes when jQuery is loaded?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).delegate('body','click', clickOutsideEvent);
});
```

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken. I actually triggered the mouseout event during my testing. So the problem remains

Comment: Really weird! I can't use it just for document.ready event but any other is fine'

Comment: Ok now I figured out what happend. Actually the browser didn't rendered the drop-down list, because it thinks that when I click on the button to bring forward the drop-down list it also triggered the click event that I assigned for the body element, which means that the optionContainer is deleted. Because browser are built to be effective(can't find any better word for describing it) the drop-down list will never be rendered. The solution is to set a timeout function.

Comment: The solution to the problem is:


$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
 $(document).delegate('body', 'click', clickOutsideEvent);
    }, 0);
});